# Paypal "CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED"

Tags: paypal, currency, credit-card

Paypal not accept INR currency when i do credit-card payment
**https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment** (POST Method)

I'm trying to pay with **INR** currency,  which is supported by PayPal, but get the **Currency is not supported** error

**Note: Using Indian Paypal account and primary currency is INR**

```
**Request:** 
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token": {
          "credit_card_id": "CARD-7MR51074AF730652RL4J724Y",
          "expire_month": 0,
          "expire_year": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "INR",
        "total": "11.61"
      },
      "description": "Monthly Subscription"
    }
  ]
}

**Response:**
{
    "name": "CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "Currency is not supported.",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "809873b4c9820"
}
```

I'm trying in spring boot, paypal dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/), `INR` is supported as you said in the question, however has a side note that tells you that:

> This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal India accounts only.

So I suppose you are not complying this note

Comment: Thanks for reply @Berto99, Yes here merchant have an indian address and customer add his credit-card to merchant account with indian address so both are indian address

Please help me to resolve this currency not support error, where i did mistake? or Is there any configuration want to change in merchant account?

Comment: @KarthickSelva the address? you need to go to `https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/` > `click ... on the Manage accounts column` > `view/edit` > `scroll to the bottom and you will see a "country: ...`. that country should be changed to the one that you need in both the business and the personal account (both the two accounts that paypal generates automatically)

Comment: Yes @Berto99 i changed both account country as India but still i got same error in direct credit-card payment api.

Note: Actually this api working fine for "USD" currency

Comment: Obviously, USD is supported everywhere, where you currency only in India... try to contact PayPal support in that case